# Sql Date in Format MMMYY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to  get current date in sql to **MMMYY** i.e. OCT13

```
select Convert(varchar(10),getdate(),6) this will generate 11 Oct 13
```

I need to get OCT13 .

Any help appreciated.

Front end application cannot do this formating. I am exporting the data from sql to another sql server
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do it in SQL, why not just get the raw `datetime` value and alter how it appears in your consuming application?

Comment: Why not handle the formatting on the front end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), 6), ' ', '') AS [MMYY]
```

Comment: Or slightly shorter SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 0),' ','')

Answer (score 8):

With the FORMAT Function its very easy to convert it to the right format:
(for SQL Sever 2012)

`SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMyy')`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), 6), ' ', '')) AS [Mon-YY]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle "DD-MON-YY" would work (you can try MON-YY in your case). 
TO_DATE(sysdate, 'MON-YY')

Also give this a try in SQL server:

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, dt, 13), 4, 3)) +
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, dt, 13), 1, 2)
```